# Scraping data from a webpage based on VIEWSTATES

Tags: python, asp.net, api, web-scraping

I'm attempting to scrape the details of all documents on [this link](https://dec.usaid.gov/dec/search/SearchResults.aspx?q=KERvY3VtZW50cy5CaWJ0eXBlX05hbWU6KCgiU3BlY2lhbCBFdmFsdWF0aW9uIikgT1IgKCJGaW5hbCBFdmFsdWF0aW9uIFJlcG9ydCIpKSk=).

The problem I'm facing is that the site is created using ASP.NET and the Viewstates aren't me to access the data directly, and I tried a mixture of beautifulSoup, Scrapy and Selenium, but to no avail. The data consists of 12782 documents whose pdf download link I need to extract from the page that redirects from each entry of the returned results on the aforementioned page.

The site also has an API [here](https://www.usaid.gov/developer/development-experience-clearinghouse-dec-api), but the catch here is that it only returns 2000 data points at any given point of time, so the ~12k data points is out of question.

Can someone help me with *ANY ONE* of the following:

- Create a scraper to get the pdf links
- Generate a query to get all the data from the API
- Any recurrence relation that helps me generate links to get the queries for the API
- Using the requests section in the API to get all the records at the same time delivered to your email

Ideally, a solution in python would be great, but if you can help me get a csv file of all the links, that would also work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, worse then viewstate, the system probably uses session(), and that is 100% server side, so you can't even get at session() from client side code. Your best bet is to the use their API - that's why they provide that. They given you a API on a silver platter - I can't imagine why you would ignore that???? At say 2000 records per API call, then that is only 6 times you call to get 12,000 records.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal that's another problem. The math seems simple but there's no limit functionality in the API docs. Hence, out of the things I asked for help in, check out number 3. Any way to limit and call the aPI to get the data in chunks?

Comment: Well, you have to go look at the api and see if it allows a date range or some such - but that would be outlined in the api calls. I would assume some criteria or some kind of range or means to limit what the API call returns. I would doubt that such a API ALWAYS returns 2000 records - so it must have some means to select or choose what you want to consume.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the problem by using the request functionality which was located [here](https://dec.usaid.gov/api/request.aspx).

It took in a particular query and my email address and sent me the entire data dump I needed. From that data dump, I could use all the pdf links.